# Is there a regular expression that can recognize positive even numbers (including numbers with leading zeros, but excluding "0000" numbers)?

Tags: regex

Like I said in the title, I am having a hard time writing this particular regular expression.
Any help would be much appreciated.

My best attempt in trying to solve this problem was writing this:

```
^([0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*)*[02468]$
```

But this regular expression can't recognize a number like "002". Then I have tried this:

```
^([0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*)*[02468]*[02468]$
```

Now regular expression recognizes "002", but also recognizes "000" (only zeros) and I can't avoid that happening.

In conclusion, I am failing again and again in writing a regular expression that can recognize positive even numbers (including leading zeros, but excluding "000" - numbers with only zeros) like:

2, 001234, 00123400, 002, 20, 16 etc.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a positive lookahead for any digit except `0`:

```
^(?=.*[1-9])[0-9]*[02468]$
```

- `(?=.*[1-9])` - positive lookahead for any digit except `0`
- `[0-9]*` - any digit repeated 0 or more times
- `[02468]` - any even digit

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Kj8WnJ/1)

Answer (score 2):

You could match at least a single digit not being zero, or match at least 2 digits where the first one is 1-9

```
^(?:[0-9]*[2468]|0*[1-9][0-9]*[02468])$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[0-9]*[2468]` Match optional digits 0-9 and then one of `2` `4` `6` `8`
  - `|` Or
  - `0*[1-9][0-9]*[02468]` Match optional zeroes, a digit 1-9 optional digits 0-9 and then one of `2` `4` `6` `8`
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/E88x8L/1)

Or you could assert not only zeroes in the string using a negative lookahead `(?!0+$)`

```
^(?!0+$)[0-9]*[02468]$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7q4Bu7/1)